# Android Button selector not working properly

Tags: android

I am using the following selector to change the color of a button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@color/darkgray" />
 <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@color/background_red_down" />
 <item android:drawable="@color/background_red" />
</selector>
```

I am getting the red color for the button but that's it. I am not getting the gray disabled color, the button is indeed disabled as it is unclickable. I am also not getting the red_down color once I click.

What have I missed?

Thanks

Comment: add state_press=false to first item tag

Comment: is my answer helpful you....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your color.xml

replace this

```
<color name="background_red">#9A9484</color>
```

to

```
<drawable name="background_red">#9A9484</drawable>
```

"**#9A9484 = your background color**"

Answer (score 0):

This is code from my button selector. Modify it's values and it should work for you.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/redtheme_btn_default_normal_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/redtheme_btn_default_disabled_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/redtheme_btn_default_pressed_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/redtheme_btn_default_focused_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/redtheme_btn_default_normal_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/redtheme_btn_default_disabled_focused_holo_light" />
    <item
         android:drawable="@drawable/redtheme_btn_default_disabled_holo_light" />
</selector>
```